# Who are all the characters who have called themselves The Wasp?

Tags: marvel, comics, the-wasp

Who are all the characters who've used the super hero persona of 'The Wasp' in the 616 version of the comics?

From what I can see on marvel.fandom.com, this was just Janet Van Dyne, and her step-daughter Nadia as well.

But I know lots of people have used the alias Ant-Man, so it seemed likely to me that the same might be true of The Wasp as well?

Answer (score 11):

Unlike her ex-husband, Hank Pym -- who's assumed a number of different guises over the years, such as Ant-Man, Giant-Man, Goliath, and Yellowjacket -- Janet Van Dyne has consistently stuck with the 'Wasp' identity during the entire time that she's been a superhero. She first adopted it in *[Tales to Astonish Vol. 1 #44](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Tales_to_Astonish_Vol_1_44)*
(March, 1963), and up until her apparent death in *[Secret Invasion #8](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Secret_Invasion_Vol_1_8)* (January, 2009), was the only character to have ever used it.

> And, as she shrinks to minuteness, gossamer, dainty wings sprout from Janet's shoulders and tiny, delicate antennae adorn her forehead! The lovely girl has truly become... the Wasp!
>
> [image: Tales to Astonish Vol. 1 #44, page 13]
>
> <sub>*Tales to Astonish Vol. 1 #44* (March, 1963)</sub>

In *[Secret Invasion: Requiem #1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Secret_Invasion:_Requiem_Vol_1_1)* (February, 2009) -- shortly after Jan's apparent death -- Hank Pym took over the mantle in her honour, becoming the second Wasp. He subsequently reverted to his Giant-Man guise in *[Avengers Academy #7](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers_Academy_Vol_1_7)* (February, 2011).

> HANK PYM: Over the years, I've reinvented myself as a super hero so many times... Ant-Man, Giant-Man, Goliath, Yellowjacket... always trying to carve out a legacy for myself. But now...? ...I can think of nothing more appropriate... than taking up someone else's mantle. The greatest hero I've ever known. Call me... the Wasp!
>
> [image: Secret Invasion: Requiem #1, page 8]
>
> [image: Secret Invasion: Requiem #1, page 9]
>
> <sub>*Secret Invasion: Requiem #1* (February, 2009)</sub>

In *[Avengers Vol. 4 #32](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers_Vol_4_32)* (December, 2012), it was revealed that Jan hadn't actually died, but was instead transported to the [Microverse](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Microverse). She was eventually rescued by the Avengers, after summoning them with a distress signal. Shortly after that, she resumed her costumed identity as the Wasp.

> [image: Uncanny Avengers Vol. 1 #5, page 5]
>
> <sub>*[Uncanny Avengers Vol. 1 #5](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/All-New,_All-Different_Avengers_Vol_1_12)* (May, 2013)</sub>

Some time later, in *[Free Comic Book Day Vol. 2016 Civil War II](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Free_Comic_Book_Day_Vol_2016_Civil_War_II)* (May, 2016),  Nadia Van Dyne constructed her own costume out of spare parts she found in Hank Pym's home, and became the third (and currently, final) Wasp in the [Earth-616](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-616) reality.

> NADIA VAN DYNE: The doctor would have taken pity on me in that moment, I know he would have. He would have forgiven me for what I felt forced to do. For laying claim to his laboratory... and to his life's work. I believe the American phrase is "Kid in a candy store." It was more... astonishing than I'd ever dared imagine. World-changing theories in every notebook. Half-finished miracles on every shelf. At my fingertips, everything I could possibly need to finish remaking myself into the girl I'd always longed to become. In Russian, "Oca." In English... the Wasp.
>
> [image: Free Comic Book Day Vol. 2016 Civil War II, page 18]
>
> <sub>*Free Comic Book Day Vol. 2016 Civil War II* (May, 2016)</sub>

Nadia met Jan in *[All-New, All-Different Avengers #10](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/All-New,_All-Different_Avengers_Vol_1_10)* (August, 2016), who effectively gave her blessing for both of them to use the 'Wasp' name concurrently a couple of issues later.

> NADIA VAN DYNE: That... was... amazing! Jan, I just hung out with the President! Of the United States! Look at all this cool stuff he gave me!
>
> JANET VAN DYNE: You did him a solid, Nadia. And you were great today. You certainly taught me a thing or two about defusing Microverse bombs. It looks like two Wasps are better than one.
>
> [image: All-New, All-Different Avengers #12, page 8]
>
> <sub>*All-New, All-Different Avengers #12* (September, 2016)</sub>

Comment: So nobody else besides Janet and Nadia?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Hank Pym adopted the 'Wasp' identity from 2009-2011.

Answer (score 4):

Short list from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasp_(character)#Other_characters_named_Wasp). It looks like it's stayed in the family

- Janet Van Dyne
- [Nadia Van Dyne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadia_van_Dyne)
- [Hope Van Dyne](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Wasp) (MCU universe)
- [Hank Pym](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Wasp%27s_Suit?file=Henry_Pym_%2528Earth-616%2529_from_Secret_Invasion_Requiem_Vol_1_1_0001.jpg) (for a brief period when Janet was believed dead)

Arguably, one might include more from [this list](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Wasp), including some Skrull, android, and LMD depictions, as well as characters like [Burton Slade](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Burton_Slade_(Earth-616)) or [Waspbunny](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Waspbunny_(Earth-8311)) who are more Wasp-adjacent.

Comment: Did he dress up in her outfit?

Comment: @Valorum: It sounds like he made his own version and implanted wings in his back.